# Way to hook into flask's file change detection?

Tags: python, flask

A friend has been using VSCode's live server functionality (he describes it as force-refreshing the browser every time he saves the file) which sounds incredibly convenient.

It got me to thinking I could write a little AJAX route and accompanying JavaScript snippet to only be included in the template's base when in DEBUG mode that continuously polls whether a file has changed in the app and then force-refreshes the browser.

The JavaScript is simple enough, but to write the file-polling seems like it would be non-trivial and possibly extremely resource-intensive. Since the Flask server has this exact functionality built into it when it's in debug mode, I was wondering if there is some way to poll *it* when the last time it restarted was.

One solution I'm pondering is using some kind of logger, though I'm not very familiar with logging (I can get familiar, if need be, of course).

Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `flask` reloads the full code, all you'd need to do is grab a timestamp at the module scope and that'll tell you when the web process started

```
# app/start_time.py
import time


server_start_time = time.time()

# ... in some view
    return jsonify({'start_time': server_start_time})
```

Your javascript heartbeat could retrieve this endpoint and when it changes refresh the page.  Perhaps something like this (untested)

```
var lastServerTime;

function checkTime() {
    fetch('/server-start-time')
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function (json) {
            if (!lastServerTime) {
                lastServerTime = json.start_time;
            } else if (lastServerTime != json.start_time) {
                window.location.reload();
            }
        });
}

setInterval(checkTime, 1000);
```

Comment: You even improved my JavaScript! Bravo!